# Laravel order by relation with join

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to get data using order by a relationsship:

```
return $this->customer->where('status', 1)
          ->whereDoesntHave('activeAssignments')
          ->with('latestDismissal')
          ->join('dismissal', 'customers.id', '=', 'dismissal.customer_id')
          ->orderBy('dismissal.valid_at_timestamp')
          ->paginate(config('app.pagination'));
```

But if i run this code, my custom accessor in the customer model dont work anymore:

`Trying to get property 'last_name' of non-object`
for this accessor:

```
public function getDisplayNameAttribute()
{
    if (!$this->toCareFirst()->first()->last_name) {
        return 'NO NAME';
    }

        return trim(
          $this->toCares()->get()->implode('display_name', ' & ')
        );
}
```

If i add `>select('customers.*')` to my query, it returns me data, but the same data 4 or 5 times...

Comment: you method the display_name property, but you need last_name, right?

Comment: A `customer` can have multiple `dismissals`. Which one do you want to use for ordering?

Comment: how can i tell them which i want? In laravel i have a relation for the latest: ```return $this->hasOne(Dismissal::class)->latest('id');```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a modified [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models):

```php
return $this->customer->where('status', 1)
    ->whereDoesntHave('activeAssignments')
    ->with('latestDismissal')
    ->withCount(['latestDismissal as dismissal_order' => function($query) {
        $query->select('valid_at_timestamp')->latest('id')->limit(1);
    }])
    ->orderBy('dismissal_order')
    ->paginate(config('app.pagination'));
```